# Is it possible to link from firebasestorage to firestoredatabase?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-storage

Is there a way to link a picture from storage to firestore like this way: "homepage/aposto.png"? Or do you have to copy the complete url?

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in linkage. You would have to store a string that represents the path to the image.  You can also store strings in the metadata of a storage object if you want to link it back to the database in some way.